# How do I reduce memory latency?

Tags: memory, performance

My environment is OpenVZ, using the 3.10.0-1160.21.1.vz7.174.13 GNU/Linux kernel.

When executing `vzstat`, I am seeing the `lat(ms)` is very high (going to assume this means latency in miliseconds):

[image]

This in turn seems to be causing kswapd to be working overtime (and resulting in sub-par performance).

My question is - what should I be doing to decrease the memory latency? Is it just a case of adding more physical RAM? Memory usage is as follows:

```
[root@nyjvz2 ~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         78G        659M        2.6G         46G         43G
Swap:           31G         25G        6.1G
[root@nyjvz2 ~]#
```

Comment: From the [manual](https://static.openvz.org/vz-man/man8/vzstat.8.gz.html): "A long allocation latency can be a sign of node’s overload." The high swap used number indicates recent paging. You can use tools like vmstat to see if paging is going on. Solution: Find large memory consumers and terminate them, or add memory. It may also help to reduce the swappiness kernel parameter, though I don't know how it impacts OpenVZ.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of words and numbers here. The only significant thing is this:

```
> Swap:           31G         25G        6.1G
```

This box is heavily into its swap - it does not have enough memory to support the tasks as they are currently configured.

If you can't reduce the memory consumption then buy more RAM (or better yet move some of the load onto a second machine - since it looks like the swapping is masking a high CPU usage).